# Tell macOS that a custom file format without a .png extension is a valid png

Tags: macos, cocoa, format

I need a custom file format for my application and I thought that I could make a superset of PNG. macOS shows previews of regular PNG files (and APNGs with a `.png` extension) in Finder. I want macOS to show a preview of my file format even though it doesn't have a `.png` extension. I need to tell macOS that files with a `.px2` extension are valid PNGs that can be decoded by a regular PNG decoder.

I've been reading [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) trying to find the right set of keys to use but I'm not having any luck. I thought that [NSExportableTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685) might be the answer but that doesn't seem to be it.

To test this, I'm changing the extension of an APNG file from `.png` to `.px2`. I realise that I could just use the `.png` but I think that could be a little confusing (both for the user and the OS).

There's a slight chance that what I'm trying to do is impossible!

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the plist that you're using for `NSExportableTypes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking at 2 different problems: one is the OS recognizing the file type and linking it to your application, the other is being able to show the preview.

The latter is going to be highly dependent upon the way that the Finder's in-built QuickLook plugin works. You may need to just implement one of those yourself.

Debugging these kinds of issues can be a little tricky, because you need to make sure macOS has assimilated your `NSExportableTypes`.  One quick check is to drop into **Terminal** and use `mdls <file of your type and extension>` and see what the `kMDItemContentType` and `kMDItemContentTypeTree` are for your file.

If it's not recognizing the extension at all, make sure it's been re-loaded by using `lsregister` which is hidden away in the LaunchServices Framework of CoreServices.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister` to get the man page

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -lint -f <path>` to force reload of your application (the `-lint`) adds more detail on errors while interpreting the entries.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed` will reset the daemon and re-seed the data from the default applications and library locations.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I think I'm way over my head. There's a lot of new terminology to learn. I shouldn't need to create my own quick look plugin although I think that's the only way. I'm beginning to think that this isn't worth the effort. `NSExportableTypes` just contains `public.png` by the way. Would you like to see the whole file? I've decided that I don't want a custom thumbnail (I want that to just be the document icon), I just want a custom preview. It might be less confusing for people that have file extensions hidden. Is this possible to achieve by just editing `Info.plist`?

Comment: I just did a proper test and I think I've just gotten what I was after! My application is just writing a plain old PNG with a different extension. The thumbnail shown in finder is the document icon but the quicklook preview shows the image. Yay! This works even without `NSExportableTypes`. This must mean that Quick Look is inspecting the first few bytes of the file and noticing that it's a PNG. So if I want my own magic number, I might need to use `NSExportableTypes`. I still don't fully understand what that key means. Could you explain it?

Comment: That would be odd.  Can you try the `mdls` command against one of your files and see what the `kMDItemContentTypeTree` looks like?  It's certainly possible that it's doing inspection of file's contents, but that would be a little surprising.

Comment: `kMDItemContentTypeTree` is `("public.item", "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge81a8bw", "public.data")`. Looks pretty generic to me.

Comment: Yes, the  dyn is auto-generated.  Otherwise, it just looks like generic data, so they must be peeking at the data when generating the QuickLook preview. Interesting.